# How to disable an href after clicking - Ajax

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to disable "liked" href after Ajax ".done" is executed. I want it unclickable. The following is the Ajax code and HTML :

```
$('.like').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLike,
        data: {postId: postId, _token: token}
    })
        .done(function() {
            event.target.innerText = 'Liked';

        });
});
```

```
<div class="interaction">
<a href="#" class="like">Like</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you need to pass `event` through as the param in the done call

Comment: Remove class `like` after clicked?

Comment: an example would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the following and it removed the href :

```
jQuery(this).removeAttr('href');
```

```
$('.like').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
   jQuery(this).removeAttr('href');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLike,
        data: {postId: postId, _token: token}
    })
        .done(function() {
            event.target.innerText = 'Liked';

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beforeSend()` and `complete()` functions to prevent further click until the [**AJAX**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is complete. In `beforeSend()` method can remove the `like` class and after completing the AJAX in `complete()` method again add the `like` class.  An example:

```
$('.like').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
    // var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null;
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLike,
        data: {postId: postId, _token: token},
        function: beforeSend() {
            $(self).removeClass('like')
        },
        function: complete() {
            $(self).addClass('like')
        }
    })
    //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm not sure why the editor is showing as if there is an extra parenthesis,  but I couldn't find any. (will add screenshot  above)

Comment: Not because of that. When I remove the functions in the middle it works:                               
           function: complete() {
            $(self).removeClass('like')
        }